# Generic way to format object as subject and body?

Tags: c#, casting, strong-typing

I am trying to take a list of objects and format these as an email subject and body. To illustrate what I am doing, take the following *examples*:

```
public string GetSubject(Person myPerson) 
{ 
    return String.Format("To {0}", myPerson.Name); 
}

public string GetMessage(Person myPerson) 
{ 
    return String.Format("Dear {0}, Your new salary: {1}", 
        myPerson.Name, myPerson.Salary); 
}

public string GetSubject(VacationDay dayOff) 
{ 
    return String.Format("Vacation reminder!"); 
}

public string GetMessage(VacationDay dayOff) 
{ 
    return String.Format("Reminder: this {0} is a vacation day!", dayOff.Name); 
}
```

Later I have a bunch of emails which I want to send in a batch:

```
// myEmailObjects is a "List<object>"
foreach (var emailItem in myEmailObjects)
{
    SendEmail(from, to, GetSubject(emailItem), GetMessage(emailItem));
}
```

The problem is this code doesn't compile because the compiler can't resolve which `GetSubject` and which `GetMessage` routine to call. Is there any generic way to write this without using an `is` or `as` operator all over the place to check for types?

Comment: Why do you have a list of objects?

Comment: @gunr2171 `emailItem` is one of three or four different strong types that I want to convert to an email. I have a `GetSubject` and `GetMessage` for each of these but was trying to make the email code as generic as possible. I already though of adding an `IEmailable` interface of sorts to each object, but this won't work as well as I would like so I was interested in seeing what other approaches people have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what *interfaces* are made for. Conceptually, an interface is like a contract that a class can sign where it obliges to define the methods that the interface specifies. Define each of the `GetSubject()` and `GetMessage()` methods as member methods of the corresponding classes instead, and then create the following interface:

```
public interface IEmailable {
    string GetSubject();
    string GetMessage();
}
```

Then, make all of the involved classes implement the interface:

```
public class VacationDay : IEmailable
```

You can now create a `List<IEmailable>()`, and you may call those two methods on its elements.

Comment: This was my first instinct as well. The message subject and body strings are created using DI from a properties file - which made this a little more difficult. Still - I agree, this is the best approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do, assuming you keep the `List<object>`, would be to check what type the iterator variable is, then choose which operation to do.

```
foreach (var emailItem in myEmailObjects)
{
    if (emailItem is Person)
    {
        SendEmail(from, to, GetSubject((Person)emailItem), 
            GetMessage((Person)emailItem));
    }
    else if (emailItem is VacationDay)
    {
        SendEmail(from, to, GetSubject((VacationDay)emailItem), 
            GetMessage((VacationDay)emailItem));
    }

}
```

Other options include making an interface (as described in another answer, but if you have a list of objects this will be hard), and to make extension methods (also hard with a list of objects).